# Wraping span around every parent text

Tags: jquery, parent-child

I have situation like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Sub link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="">Link 2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Sub link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And I need to wrap span tag around ever text if it has child element. So this firtst li needs to look like

```
<li><a href="#"><span>Link 1</span></a>
```

It need to go unlimited it dept :

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <ul n>
           <li n>
```

I don't even have idea how to solve this. I tired something like:

```
$('li').parent().wrapInner('<span />');
```

But its not it.

I would appreciate any help.

Tnx,

Comment: I'm confused. What do you mean by *"around ever text if it has child element"*. That isn't making sense to me.

Comment: If the `li` has a child `ul` wrap the `a` (or the text of the `a`) in a `span`? Could you post the code for what you want the modified DOM to look like after manipulation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$("li:has(ul) > a").wrapInner("<span />")
```

select the anchor tag of every list element that has a child list and wrap it's contents in a span tag.

http://jsfiddle.net/Tentonaxe/EKjfT/

Edit: in response to the jsperf(Jasper), try this one out: http://jsperf.com/jquery-has-vs/3

```
$("li").has("ul").children("a").wrapInner("<span />");
```

Thanks for pointing that out Jasper. It is usually faster to not use selector methods in your selector and to instead use the actual methods, such as .has instead of :has, or .eq instead of :eq

Edit: But, not always... http://jsperf.com/recursive-text-wrap seems to favor my first one

Answer (score 2):

```
$('li ul').parents('li').children('a').wrapInner('<span />');
```

This should be a fast method, I answered a question similar yesterday and made a jsperf: http://jsperf.com/jquery-has-vs

Here is a jsfiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/n9Ew8/2/

Docs:

`.siblings()`: http://api.jquery.com/siblings

`.wrapInner()`: http://api.jquery.com/wrapinner